# Laravel timing with carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I try to show `new label` in my app depending on products publishing time.

## Logic

1. Show label new since product publishing time `created_at` till `20
   days` after.

## Code

this is what I did so far, but not sure about it.

```
$new = Product::where('created_at', '=<', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));
```

`screenshot`

[image: screenone]

*this label must be shown only first 20 days.*

#### Question

1. How do I make `if statement` in my blade for `$new`? (i mean i created `@if($new)...@endif` it doesn't work)
2. Is my code correct?

## UPDATE

`my page controller`

```
$products = DB::table('products')
              ->join('page-views','products.id','=','page-views.visitable_id')
              ->select(DB::raw('count(visitable_id) as count'),'products.*')
              ->groupBy('id')
              ->orderBy('count','desc')
              ->having('count', '>=', 100)
              ->get();
```

PS: I have to add I added code below **Base on Quezler answer** to my model even on my normal collection such as `$products = Product::all();` gives same error.

`error`

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$new
```

`model`

```
public function getNewAttribute(): boolean
    {
        return (clone $this->created_at)->addDays(20)->greaterThanOrEqualTo(Carbon::now());
    }
```

Comment: `$new = Product::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30));`, changed the less than or equals to symbol

Comment: @ShobiPP and for blade part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `Product` model:

```
public function getNewAttribute(): bool
{
    return (clone $this->created_at)->addDays(20)->greaterThanOrEqualTo(Carbon::now());
}
```

Then in blade you can do `@if($product->new)` while handeling products.

Comment: `Undefined property: stdClass::$new`

Comment: can you share the rest of your blade view?

Comment: is a long blade but is like `@if(count($products) > 0) @foreach($products as $product) {{$product->title}} @if($product->new) ... @endif @endforeach @endif`

Comment: Appologies, `getNewAttribute` instead of `isNewAttribute`

Comment: still same error `Undefined property: stdClass::$new `

Comment: looks like the foreach loop is not giving the product somehow, and the `{{$product->title}}` does show? can you share the controller code that retrieves the model from the database?

Comment: yes in my screenshot is real result of my products. everything show

Comment: under the `$products = DB::` query, add this: `$products = Product::hydrate($products);`

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::hydrate() must be of the type array, object given, called in ` what is `hydrate do?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171795/discussion-between-quezler-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

In controller on the basis of created date set a new variable i.e. $isNew

```
$created = new Carbon($products->created_at);
$now = Carbon::now();
$isNew = ($created->diff($now)->days < 20)? True: FALSE;
```

And pass to the view. In view just check that

@if($isNew)?.....@endif

or you can do direct comparison in view

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($product->created_at, false) < 20)
```

//place your HTML here

```
@endif
```